# Connecting ordinary 3.5mm speakers to S/PDIF?

Tags: speakers

Not sure if this is the best place for this question, but here goes anyway. I recently got myself the [Logitech Revue](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/smartTV/accessories/devices/revue-tvcam-bundle?WT.mc_id=AMR_Revue_Branded_GAW_Q2_FY12&WT.srch=1&gclid=CNeWpZXwrqsCFQw65QodOiYfIw) to stream Netflix etc. However, my TV has extremely poor 7W speakers and that makes me want to use my computer's speakers (2.1). Now the Revue only has an Audio optical output (S/PDIF) and my computer's speakers use a 3.5mm jack. Does anyone know of a way to connect these, or if it's even possible?
TIA!

Comment: Sure it possible, just search for S/PDIF, optical, DA-Converter.

Comment: Home theater questions [aren't really on topic here](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/204/are-non-production-video-and-audio-questions-on-topic-here) but [there is a site proposal in Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2274/home-theater). However, navigating audio and S/PDIF is not uncommon in home studios so I chose to just answer the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't connect them with an ordinary audio adapter like one might expect, because the signals are fundamentally different. Your computer speakers expect an analog audio signal, but S/PDIF is a digital format.

So you'll need some kind of device to accept digital S/PDIF in and translate it into analog audio out. I wouldn't know what to call them if I were trying to go find a device for this specific purpose, but many recording interfaces include S/PDIF and can perform this function, so I imagine they exist.

Comment: DAC these devices are called, simple as that. Or the obvious "S/PDIF to analog-" / "Optical to RCA-" - "-converter".

Comment: I found this puppy on amazon: http://www.amazon.com/FiiO-Digital-Analog-Audio-Converter/dp/B0053VKP8S/ref=dp_cp_ob_e_title_0 - will give this a shot. Thanks, Bob and leftaroundabout!